# How to remove a decrypted Androis 4.1 phone?

Tags: lock-screens, encryption

I tried out encrypting the phone, but now I want to decrypt it, so I can use again pattern to unlock. How can I do this without resetting the phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I only could reset the phone.. cannot remove the encryption.